# Abort connection when database is read-only (Flask/SQLAlchemy)

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am facing the following issue:

We have configured failover DB nodes for our staging environment. When testing, sometimes the failover happens and Flask keeps open connections to some nodes which are now read-only -- any write operation then fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
cursor, statement, parameters, context
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticapm/instrumentation/packages/dbapi2.py", line 210, in execute
return self.trace_sql(self.wrapped_.execute, sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticapm/instrumentation/packages/dbapi2.py", line 244, in _trace_sql
result = method(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.ReadOnlySqlTransaction: cannot execute DELETE in a read-only transaction
```

I'd like to detect this somehow and close the connection to these nodes, so that any write operation succeeds. Is this possible?

Comment: This might be relevant https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2021/02/12/reconnecting-your-app-after-a-postgres-failover/

Answer (score 0):

You can import that error class into your module, and then use it in a try-except block:

```
from psycopg2.errors import ReadOnlySqlTransaction

try:
    # your main stuff here
except ReadOnlySqlTransaction:
    # terminate the connection
```

Comment: Would this apply to _every_ connection? I mean, where in a Flask application would this go into?

Comment: That's harder to say without knowing the scope / structure of your project. Wherever the code that is causing the issue is, that's where this should go. If it appears in multiple files, consider consolidating it into a separate module and importing that into your other files.